# Having a function set a global variable

Tags: python, c++, global-variables, global, python-c-api

Consider the following C++ module (explanation to follow):

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "nr3python.h"

Doub tau_0;

static PyObject* analysis_c_set_parameters(PyObject *self, PyObject *pyargs) {
  NRpyArgs args(pyargs);
  Doub tau_0 = NRpyDoub(args[0]);
  return NRpyObject();
}

Doub solver(const Doub t) {
  return tau_0;
}

static PyObject* analysis_c_solver(PyObject *self, PyObject *pyargs) {
  NRpyArgs args(pyargs);
  const Doub t = NRpyDoub(args[0]);
  const Doub result = solver(t);
  return NRpyObject(result);
}

static PyMethodDef AnalysisCMethods[] = {
  {"set_parameters", analysis_c_set_parameters, METH_VARARGS,
   "Set fixed parameters for the optimization procedure."},
  {"solver", analysis_c_solver, METH_VARARGS,
   "Call the optimization function for solving for the spike time."},
  {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initanalysis_c(void)
{
  (void) Py_InitModule("analysis_c", AnalysisCMethods);
}
```

Note that this module is setup so that its functions can be imported into Python scripts.

I have a global variable `tau_0`, which is declared without an initial value.  The value is set (or should be set) when the function `analysis_c_set_parameters` is called (within Python).  This value is then read out when `analysis_c_solver` is called: `analysis_c_solver` calls `solver`, which returns `tau_0`.  `analysis_c_solver` then returns `tau_0`.

The problem I'm facing is that when I call these functions in Python script, I get `0.0` as the value for `tau_0` even after I've attempted to set it to something else (e.g., `0.5`).

In Python I have

```
import analysis_c


TAU_0 = 0.5
t = 0

analysis_c.set_parameters(TAU_0)
actual_result = analysis_c.solver(t)
```

In this case, `actual_result` is set to `0.0`.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line declares and initialises a new local variable:

```
Doub tau_0 = NRpyDoub(args[0]);
```

To assign to the global variable that you already declared you need to write

```
tau_0 = NRpyDoub(args[0]);
```

Comment: "To assign to the global variable that you ashtray decanted" - wrong autocorrect there?

Comment: ah, bingo, yep, that's it.  apparently the tutorial i followed is buggy (it told me to restate the declaration.)

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah. Must remember to proofread when using touchscreen. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are defining a local variable that hides the global variable:

```
Doub tau_0;

static PyObject* analysis_c_set_parameters(PyObject *self, PyObject *pyargs) {
  NRpyArgs args(pyargs);
  Doub tau_0 = NRpyDoub(args[0]);  // here you are defining a local tau_0
  return NRpyObject();
}
```